# Android - Sending Images to server generate huge HTTP request

Tags: android, imageview, base64, multipart, okhttp

I'm currently sending an image to my server by encoding it into a base64 string like this: https://gist.github.com/fabdarice/a4006a97171cc415892e

However, when I'm looking at the HTTP POST request, I'm seeing something like this :

```
{"login"=>"Jerem", "mobile_upload_file"=>"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB\nAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB\nAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/wAARCAQ4BDgDASIA\nAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQA\nAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3\nODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWm\np6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEA\nAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3....................................}
```

This goes on for a while, (around 1 millions characters) and it seems to make my server laggy.

I was wondering if this is a normal behavior to see that amount of characters sent? If not, how am I supposed to implement the process of sending an image to a server?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just send the image 'as is'. Base64 encoding makes the amount of bytes 30% more. Do not use json to upload images.

Comment: by 'as is', you mean send the images as an array of bytes? basically to send the results of : byte[] bytes = fileToByteArray(file.getPath()); ?

Comment: could you show me an example?

Comment: Are you going to change the software on your server too?

Answer (score 0):

You can send image in FileBody by Multipart entity like this...

```
public String sendMultipartRequestToServer(BusinessDataObject dataObject,String url) {
    String responseString=null;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post=new HttpPost(url);
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(),50000);
    MultipartEntity multipartEntity=new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    try {
        multipartEntity.addPart(KEY_EMAIL,new StringBody(dataObject.getEmail()));   
        multipartEntity.addPart(KEY_PASSWORD, new StringBody(dataObject.getPassword()));
        multipartEntity.addPart(KEY_IMAGE,new FileBody(new File(Here your image path on your memory)));

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
            //Setting parameter to post method
        post.setEntity(multipartEntity);
        try {
            response=client.execute(post);
            InputStream inputStream=response.getEntity().getContent();
            responseString=convertStreamToString(inputStream);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseString;          
}
```

If you will not find the class MultipartEntity .Then you have to add HttpMime.jar in your project .It is the best way to send images so far i know here no need to convert image in Base64.You can just pass the url of selected image to FileBody.

Comment: Both MultipartEntity and DefaultHttpClient are deprecated now. So you could have converted this first i think.

Comment: Okay then i have to find other way to do it . But i used Multipart in my code so thats why i recomended it.

Comment: You can now use HttpUrlConnection and MultiPartEntityBuilder i think. Converting your ĉode will not take much time.

Comment: yeah i got HttpUrlConnection and will see about MultiPartEntityBuilder  .. Thx